# Create a list of templates from a json with loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Need to create a loop in a JSON file to get the URL (path) to the templates and create a list of templates...

What i do wrong?

```js
//get the JSON file from the server
$http.get('static/titles.json').success(function(doc){
  $scope.docs = doc;
  //preenche os templates a partir do JSON.
  fillTemplatesList();
 }).error(function(error){
  console.log(error);
 });


$scope.templates = [];

 function fillTemplatesList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.docs.length; i++) {
   $scope.templates[i].url = $scope.docs[i].url;
   console.log($scope.templates.url);
  }
  
 }

//when user clicks, the page changes.
$scope.cliked = function(index){
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[index];
  console.log(index);
 };
```

```html
<div id="container-doc" class="col s9">
  <br>
    <div class="container left" ng-include="template.url">
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are several problems from what I can see, however you can do some thing like this:

```
<div id="container-doc" class="col s9" ng-controller="myCtrl as myCtrl">
  <br>
    <div class="container left" ng-include="myCtrl.template.url">

    </div>
    <button ng-click="clicked()">Click</button>
  </div>
```

And then in your JS:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', [])

var json = ['home.html', 'test.html'];
function myController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.index =0;
  vm.template = {url : json[vm.index]}
  $scope.clicked = function () {
    vm.index = 0 + !vm.index
    vm.template.url = json[vm.index];
  }
}

myapp.controller('myCtrl', myController)
```

So I would just maintain the list of urls, there doesn't seem any need to parse them again with the fillTemplatesList function.
Then when you click you can just change the index, based on some simple logic.

Experiment with this plunkr, you can put your json array in place of mine:

[plunky](https://plnkr.co/edit/zND9Yz)

However it would seem this is just really trying to do ng-routing and so I would look at that and perhaps get a sample ng-route plunkr going from the massive pile of templates there.